# Android: Draw two strings in an arch next to each other on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas

**Why this question is not a duplicate**: The reference question explains how to add a single string to a curved path.. I'm trying to find out how to to add two strings with different fonts/styles to a curved path

---

I have two string that need to be drawn with different styles on the upper part of a circle.

I have tried a couple of things but all I manage to achieve is to draw each string on top of each other or on opposite ends (with a huge gap between them).

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Arched text]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class LabeledImageView extends ImageView
{
    Path path;
    Paint infoTextPaint;
    Paint titleTextPaint;

    String stringTitle = "Test name ";
    String stringInfo = "0/20";

    public LabeledImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    private void buildArch()
    {
        int textColor = Color.WHITE;

        float cx = (float) getWidth() / 2.0f;
        float cy = (float) getHeight() / 2.0f;

        Point textSizePoint;
        float rInn;
        float rOut;
        float endX;

        float varTextSize = 14.0f;

        CFTextView temp = new CFTextView(getContext());//CFTextView is a TextView that uses a custom font
        temp.setSingleLine(true);
        temp.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        temp.setText(stringTitle + stringInfo);
        temp.setLayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        (int) ((cx / 2.0f) * Math.PI),
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
        );
        temp.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        do
        {
            temp.setTextSize(varTextSize);

            textSizePoint = Utils.measureView(
                    getContext(),
                    (int) ((cx / 2.0f) * Math.PI),
                    temp,
                    true
            );//This method forces the view to draw and returns a Point with the final size of the view

            rInn = (float) getWidth() / 2.0f;
            rOut = rInn + textSizePoint.y;

            endX = (float) textSizePoint.x / 2.0f;

            varTextSize--;
        }while(endX >= rOut);

        float textSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                varTextSize,
                Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()
        );

        float smallTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                varTextSize - 2 > 2 ? varTextSize - 2 : varTextSize,
                Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()
        );

        float angle = 90.0f - (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(endX / rOut));

        float startAngle = -(angle + 90.0f);
        float sweepAngle = 2.0f * angle;

        titleTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        titleTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        titleTextPaint.setColor(textColor);
        titleTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        titleTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        titleTextPaint.setTypeface(
                FontManager.getFontUrl(
                        getContext(),
                        Typeface.BOLD
                )//FontManager.getFontUrl returns a custom TypeFace
        );

        infoTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        infoTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        infoTextPaint.setColor(textColor);
        infoTextPaint.setTextSize(smallTextSize);
        infoTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        infoTextPaint.setTypeface(
                FontManager.getFontUrl(
                        getContext(),
                        Typeface.NORMAL
                )//FontManager.getFontUrl returns a custom TypeFace
        );

        path = new Path();
        float r = rInn;
        r += textSize * 0.1f;
        RectF segment = new RectF(cx - r, cy - r, cx + r, cy + r);
        path.addArc(segment, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(path == null && getWidth() > 0)
        {
            buildArch();
        }

        if(path != null)
        {
            canvas.drawTextOnPath(
                    stringTitle,
                    path,
                    0,
                    0,
                    titleTextPaint
            );

            canvas.drawTextOnPath(
                    stringInfo,
                    path,
                    0,
                    0,
                    infoTextPaint
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was about to set a bounty on this question I got an idea.. and it worked :D

I calculated half the size of the title text and added it as an horizontal offset to the draw call for the `stringInfo` and subtracted half the size of the info text to the horizontal offset to the draw call for the `stringTitle`.

Here is the full code:

```
public class LabeledImageView extends ImageView
{
    Path path;
    Paint infoTextPaint;
    Paint titleTextPaint;

    String stringTitle = "Test name ";
    String stringInfo = "0/20";

    float titleHorizontalOffset = 0.0f;//Added this line
    float infoHorizontalOffset = 0.0f;//Added this line

    public LabeledImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    private void buildArch()
    {
        int textColor = Color.WHITE;

        float cx = (float) getWidth() / 2.0f;
        float cy = (float) getHeight() / 2.0f;

        Point textSizePoint;
        float rInn;
        float rOut;
        float endX;

        float varTextSize = 14.0f;

        CFTextView temp = new CFTextView(getContext());//CFTextView is a TextView that uses a custom font
        temp.setSingleLine(true);
        temp.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        temp.setText(stringTitle + stringInfo);
        temp.setLayoutParams(
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        (int) ((cx / 2.0f) * Math.PI),
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )
        );
        temp.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        do
        {
            temp.setTextSize(varTextSize);

            textSizePoint = Utils.measureView(
                    getContext(),
                    (int) ((cx / 2.0f) * Math.PI),
                    temp,
                    true
            );//This method forces the view to draw and returns a Point with the final size of the view

            rInn = (float) getWidth() / 2.0f;
            rOut = rInn + textSizePoint.y;

            endX = (float) textSizePoint.x / 2.0f;

            varTextSize--;
        }while(endX >= rOut);

        float textSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                varTextSize,
                Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()
        );

        float smallTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                varTextSize - 2 > 2 ? varTextSize - 2 : varTextSize,
                Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()
        );

        float angle = 90.0f - (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(endX / rOut));

        float startAngle = -(angle + 90.0f);
        float sweepAngle = 2.0f * angle;

        titleHorizontalOffset = endX;//Added this line

        temp.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        temp.setText(stringInfo);
        temp.setTextSize(smallTextSize);
        infoHorizontalOffset = Utils.measureView(
                getContext(),
                (int) ((cx / 2.0f) * Math.PI),
                temp,
                true
        ).x;//Added this line

        titleTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        titleTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        titleTextPaint.setColor(textColor);
        titleTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        titleTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        titleTextPaint.setTypeface(
                FontManager.getFontUrl(
                        getContext(),
                        Typeface.BOLD
                )//FontManager.getFontUrl returns a custom TypeFace
        );

        infoTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        infoTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        infoTextPaint.setColor(textColor);
        infoTextPaint.setTextSize(smallTextSize);
        infoTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        infoTextPaint.setTypeface(
                FontManager.getFontUrl(
                        getContext(),
                        Typeface.NORMAL
                )//FontManager.getFontUrl returns a custom TypeFace
        );

        path = new Path();
        float r = rInn;
        r += textSize * 0.1f;
        RectF segment = new RectF(cx - r, cy - r, cx + r, cy + r);
        path.addArc(segment, startAngle, sweepAngle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(path == null && getWidth() > 0)
        {
            buildArch();
        }

        if(path != null)
        {
            canvas.drawTextOnPath(
                    stringTitle,
                    path,
                    -titleHorizontalOffset,//Changed this line
                    0,
                    titleTextPaint
            );

            canvas.drawTextOnPath(
                    stringInfo,
                    path,
                    infoHorizontalOffset - titleHorizontalOffset,//Changed this line
                    0,
                    infoTextPaint
            );
        }
    }
}
```